# Numlock key pad not working vb.net textbox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, num-lock

I have noticed that my textbox will not accept numbers from the num lock key pad how do I allow this in vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

There's no restriction I know of. Either you've not activated NUMLOCK (thus making the keys act like cursor keys) or something is intercepting them (some other program).

From a VB.NET application's point of view, a key pad key is as good as any other. To be extra sure, try what happens in Visual Studio when you enter numbers using the key pad.